# How can I calculate the area within a contour in R?

Tags: r, area, contour

I'm wondering if it is possible to caclulate the area within a contour in R.

For example, the area of the contour that results from:

```
sw<-loess(m~l+d)
mypredict<-predict(sw, fitdata) # Where fitdata is a data.frame of an x and y matrix

contour(x=seq(from=-2, to=2, length=30), y=seq(from=0, to=5, length=30), z=mypredict)
```

Sorry, I know this code might be convoluted. If it's too tough to read. Any example where you can show me how to calculate the area of a simply generated contour would be helpful.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you mean area *within* a contour?

Comment: How is the contour defined (an example)... what area do you want?  If you've got coordinates of a boundary it's relatively easy.

Comment: Yes. The area within a contour. @John: I'll edit an example into my original question.

Comment: OK, so now that you've provided an example I'm wondering if you want the volume under that contour to 0 or if you want the area of the surface defined by that contour.  And, if the area of the surface, do you mean the total area 3-dimensionally or just the 2d area.

Comment: @John: Just the 2-dimensional area. So if my contour looks like a circle, I'm looking for the area of that circle like object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @DWin for reproducible example, and to the authors of `sos` (my favourite R package!) and `splancs` ...

```
library(sos)
findFn("area polygon compute")
library(splancs)
with(clines[[9]],areapl(cbind(x,y)))
```

Gets the same answer as @DWin, which is comforting.  (Presumably it's the same algorithm, but implemented within a Fortran routine in the `splancs` package ...)

Comment: I don't deserve much credit since I just went to the `help(contourlInes)` page and grabbed the example there. @BurtonGuster should feel free to give Ben the check mark. I should probably donate a few thousand points to Ben for all the good work he has posted here and on the R-help mailing list. Likewise to Hadley and Gabor Grothendeick

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to assume you are working with an object returned by contourLines. (An unnamed list with x and y components at each level.) I was expecting to find this in an easy to access location but instead found a pdf file that provided an algorithm  which I vaguely remember seeing http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/PBSmapping/doc/PBSmapping-UG.pdf  (See pdf page 19, labeled "-11-") (Added note: The Wikipedia article on "polygon" cites this discussion of the Surveyors' Formula: http://www.maa.org/pubs/Calc_articles/ma063.pdf , which justifies my use of abs().)

Building an example:

```
 x <- 10*1:nrow(volcano)
 y <- 10*1:ncol(volcano)
contour(x, y, volcano); 
clines <- contourLines(x, y, volcano)
x <- clines[[9]][["x"]]
 y <- clines[[9]][["y"]]
 level <- clines[[9]][["level"]]
 level
#[1] 130
```

The area at level == 130 (chosen because there are not two 130 levels and it doesn't meet any of the plot boundaries) is then:

```
A = 0.5* abs( sum( x[1:(length(x)-1)]*y[2:length(x)] - y[1:(length(x)-1)]*x[2:length(x)] ) )
A
#[1] 233542.1
```